# How to allow Java only for specific webpages?

Tags: windows, firefox, java

I read constantly in the news about security holes in Java, so I thought that I should not allow any webpage execute Java programs, unless I allow. And currently there is a huge security problem, and update comes at next month. So, for now I simply have uninstalled Java, to prevent any chance of infections.

On top of that, I mostly use Java for one webpage only.

I use Firefox (14.0.1), if there is a plugin for that, it would be great. It would be even better if I could choose which Java filenames can be run (on that website).

Answer (score 1):

The [QuickJava](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quickjava) add-on for Firefox allows you to enable/disable Java straight from the toolbar or status bar. You should be able to keep Java disabled, and enable it only when you visit that one site that requires it.

Comment: this is very nice, i can easily move the buttons i need next to the url bar. the problem is, i might forget the java to be enabled when i exit the website i use... it would be best if it asked for every java program "do you want to allow this java for this site?" and remember my choices.

Answer (score 0):

NoScript is a favorite and very well known among many: http://noscript.net/ .

Comment: looks good, but how do you change the language? my language version is full of typos, and i have hard time understanding it.

Comment: is it somehow possible to allow all JavaScripts but ask confirmation for Java programs for every site? I dont want to surf on random sites while clicking "allow" for every site... except for java.

Comment: @Rookie Did you look through the documentation? http://noscript.net/features

Comment: no, i just checked all the menu buttons... couldnt find any. do you mean there is such a feature, or you want me to find out if there is?

Comment: @Rookie I think section 1.12 (http://noscript.net/faq/#qa1_12) is what you are asking.